# how to make my video become a responsive web

Tags: html, css, video, bootstrap-4

How to make my video become a responsive on my web page ?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 " style="background-color:dark;">
            <video width="800" height="450" controls>
                <source src="video/seatoskygondola.mp4" type="video/mp4">    
                <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.  
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]
Thank you very much!

Comment: Haven't a clue what you define as "responsive".

Comment: When web page in difference size:  bootstrap as col-sm-4 col-md-4 etc. All are float to the left side for easy viewing.

Comment: Thank Ichigo Kurosaki to edit my question. I am new and was my first time. Thank to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Please just add the following:

```
video {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

You need to make the images responsive also, so please try the following:

```
img, video {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Now the video is small, but it depends on the styles you applied to the container.

Comment: Thank you. In large and medium screen ,video becomes smaller. In small screen ,it fit in it. Still can't solve my problem. Need to add more . Here is my web site: http://tsangwangwang.com/vancouverthegondolasquamish.html

Comment: According to his response to a question in the comments, this doesn't answer his question at all.

Comment: No luck. I tried to add both. But still not solve my problem. Can we use bootstrap ( col-sm-? col-md-? ) to solve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem myself by changing:

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 " style="background-color:dark;">
```

into

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 " style="background-color:dark;">
```

You can check the web page:

http://tsangwangwang.com/vancouverthegondolasquamish.html